# annotate cannot find rake executable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, annotate

I'm using [ctran/annotate_models](https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) to annotate my models and route files.  I'm now getting an error:

```
$ annotate -r
$ROOT/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:151:in `block in cripple_rubygems': can't find executable rake (Gem::Exception)
from $ROOT/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Route file annotated.
```

...with the result that `annotate` adds the comment block to config/routes.db, but the comment is empty.  The message suggests that `annotate` can't find `rake`, but `rake` is certainly there:

```
$ which rake
$ROOT/usr/bin/rake
```

and here's what rake says about the current configuration:

```
$ rake about
About your application's environment
Ruby version              1.9.2 (x86_64-darwin10.6.0)
RubyGems version          1.3.7
Rack version              1.2
Rails version             3.0.5
Active Record version     3.0.5
Action Pack version       3.0.5
Active Resource version   3.0.5
Action Mailer version     3.0.5
Active Support version    3.0.5
Application root          .../myapp
Environment               development
```

The only things that's slightly odd in my Gemfile is that I am specifying a previous version of rake:

```
# file: Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'             # workaround "uninitialized constant Rake::DSL" bug
...
gem 'annotate', '2.4.0'
```

Any ideas of what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `bundle exec rake` instead.

Comment: I typed `bundle exec rake` and got the same error message.  But perhaps I didn't understand your comment: try using `bundle exec rake` instead of what?